# Mas de dos roles en YII2

Tags: users-roles

Buen día,
Quiero crear tres roles en YII2.
Rol 1= Administrador = Que pueda ver las acciones ver, editar, crear.
Rol 2= Usuario = Que pueda ver las acciones Crear, Ver.
Rol 3= Revisor = Que pueda ver sólo la acción Ver.

Yo había pensado crear una tabla usuarios, y una pagina inicial donde una vez validado redireccionara a los archivos que personalizaría con  'template' => '{delete}{view}{create} en  'class' => '\kartik\grid\ActionColumn', pero me parece que es engorroso se crean muchos archivos innecesarios y en especial el tema de seguridad, entonces me gustaría hacerlo con las opciones de usuario que ofrece YII2, he leido algo sobre RBAC, pero en todos los post se hablan solo de dos roles y yo quiero que sean 3.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

puedes crear los roles que desea con el RBAC solo sigue la [guia](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/es/security-authorization), si deseas restringir el acceso solo aplicas los permisos que deseas para cada rol (Adm: create, update, view | Usu: create | Revi: view ), luego para que pueda validar los permisos, incluye este codigo en tu controlador:

```
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

$behaviors['access'] = [
    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
            'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {

                $action     =   Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
                $controller =   Yii::$app->controller->id;
                $route      =   "$controller/$action";
                $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
                if (\Yii::$app->user->can($route)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
];
```

Lo agregar el la función `behaviors`, este código te permite obtener la ruta de cualquier acción declarada en tu controlador (Ejm: "$controller/$action" > "articulo/index"). esta ruta la registras como un permiso y se lo asignas a un rol:

```
Rol                  Permisos/ruta:

Administrador:       articulo/view, articulo/update, articulo/create.
Usuario:             articulo/create, articulo/view.
Revisor:             articulo/view.
```